# Change Zend Framework Default Module

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-modules

I'm working on a project and have the following project layout:

```
|Project
    |-Application
        |-api
        |-configs
        |-controllers
        |-models
        |-modules
            |-core
                |-controllers
                |-models
                |-views
                |-Bootstrap.php
            |-site1
            |-site2
            |-site3
        |-views
        |-Bootstrap.php
    |-Docs
    |-Library
    |-Public
    |-.zfproject.xml
```

I've used this in my application.ini to try and set the `default` module to be the `core` module:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

resources.frontController.defaultModule = "core"
resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "Index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"

resources.modules[] = ""
```

My problem is that for some reason, I can't get bootstraps working in the modules. It's alsmost as if the default module isn't being changed. The application behaves like it is, until I try and load the bootstraps - I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Resource_Exception'
>   with message 'Bootstrap file found for module "default" but bootstrap
>   class "Default_Bootstrap" not found' in
>   M:\Zend_Framework\library\Zend\Application\Resource\Modules.php on
>   line 85

Prefixed by this error:

> Zend_Application_Resource_Exception: Bootstrap file found for module
>   "default" but bootstrap class "Default_Bootstrap" not found in
>   M:\Zend_Framework\library\Zend\Application\Resource\Modules.php on
>   line 85

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

My Application/Bootstrap.php file:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
}
```

My Application/Core/Bootstrap.php file:

```
class Core_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap 
{   
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not 100% on this but if you remove the following line:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
```

that may resolve the issue. If i'm not mistaken, as you're using modules, setting this will cause an error.

Comment: This has indeed fixed it!

Doing a print_r of the modules detected in Zend_Application_Resource_Module now returns an array of all my modules EXCLUDING the 'default one'!

Comment: WOW! Thanks, thanks, thanks! I was in the second week with this problem in my Unit test, now is resolved!! o/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be missing one line from your application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = ""
```

Try using it this way and see if it works, I think this just tells the app that when using modules, the module named *'default'* has no prefix.
Although I could be wrong so you may have to experiment.
Ok, maybe two lines are missing :)

```
resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectoryName = "controllers"
```