# Defining default module in Zend framework doesn't work

Tags: php, zend-framework, module

I've read a book titled zend framework:  beginner's guide. It was mentioned that it's best practice to create modules and categorize things.

I've added the modules directory to the application directory and moved views,controllers and models directory into it. The structure is as below:

**application**

- configs
- modules
- Bootstrap.php

when I pop open the browser and surf to the following URLs:

```
localhost/square/default/index/index
```

OR

```
localhost/square/public/default/index/index
```

I get `not found` error message. I've changed the configuration file (application.ini) as below:

```
resources.frontcontroller.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/default/controllers"
resources.frontcontroller.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontcontroller.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules = ""
```

I've read the following questions, but that didn't help:

[Change Zend Framework Default Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034797/change-zend-framework-default-module)

[Zend Framework not include the default module in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068776/zend-framework-not-include-the-default-module-in-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this instead :

```
resources.frontcontroller.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
```

**EDIT :**

I noticed that you use localhost/square/ to access your pages. You have to setup a virtual host to fix your problem since the router need it to work properly.

See : http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html#learning.quickstart.create-project.vhost

Comment: My app path is not as you said. I've moved them all into the modules directory.

Comment: In the App directory I don't have `controllers` folder.

Comment: I understood your app path. I just said that you have to remove "/modules/default" since it is automatically added. see http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.frontcontroller

Comment: I still receive `404 not found`. What is the issue? Do you need all the directories structure?

Answer (score 1):

this should work.

```
resources.modules[] = ""    
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectoryName = "controllers"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.env = APPLICATION_ENV
```

Comment: I still access my site through `http://localhost/square/public/index.php`, but your method to access through `http://localhost/square/default/index/index` is not working! What can be the issue? Do you need all the directories structure?

Comment: You didn't setup virtual host of project.
By default, `index.php` is in public folder.
In this case, go http://localhost/square/public/default/index/index and see the result.
If you want to remove `public` from url, try setup a virtual host, more here http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.rewrite.html
or
put `index.php` in the root of project then edit your config path, but this solution is not recommended because of security issues.

i speak English not well, sorry.

Comment: Although I added the public part, the same error(404 not found) happened!

Comment: hello.

http://www.mediafire.com/?jq8rlxuglb8tbm8

this is my sample configuration (no virtual host setup), hope that help!